# nginx only returns part of html

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

I have an issue whereby only part of the html is returned for a page. Essentially the page loops through a table and returns a long list of products but just randomly breaks off and then displays all the html up to a certain point.

Oddly if I echo out a lot of data just at the top of the page, it then returns all the html. I'm not sure what it could be but think it may be related to perhaps an nginx or php config. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Are you displaying PHP errors. It sounds like your code is hitting a fatal error and crashing, that is why you have the output up to that point and no more.

Comment: For that mater, I suspect a OOM error; you are loading a 'long list of products', this may be using up your memory limit.

Comment: @SH That would make sense but by adding the echo with some random text at the top of the html it stops the problem (please see comment below).

Comment: @SH Apologies for the late reply. I've buffed up the memory in php-fpm but that doesn't seem to have had an impact.

Comment: Do you have a code sample. Of the code that is in error?